# PostgreSQL concatenate two tables on each row

Tags: postgresql, concatenation

I have two tables, as such (where `value` in all cases is a `character varying`):

`table_one`:

```
|id|value|
|--+-----|
|1 |A    |
|2 |B    |
|3 |C    |
|4 |D    |
```

`table_two`:

```
|id|value|
|--+-----|
|11|0    |
|12|1    |
|13|2    |
|14|3    |
|15|4    |
|16|5    |
```

I want to do a query that results in the following:

result:

```
|value|
|-----|
|A_0  |
|A_1  |
|A_2  |
|A_3  |
|A_4  |
|A_5  |
|B_0  |
|B_1  |
|B_2  |
|B_3  |
|B_4  |
|B_5  |
|C_0  |
|C_1  |
|C_2  |
|C_3  |
|C_4  |
|C_5  |
|D_0  |
|D_1  |
|D_2  |
|D_3  |
|D_4  |
|D_5  |
```

This is for a seldom run report on PostgreSQL 8.4.9, so performance isn't critical. If the answer is 9.x specific, upgrading certainly isn't out of the question, so feel free to give 9.x specific answers. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select
 table_one.val || '_' || table_two.val
from
 table_one
 cross join table_two
```

Documentation for [cross join](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/queries-table-expressions.html).

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!11/08e25/2)

Comment: Better `table_one cross join table_two`.

Comment: Also do not link to old versions of documentation. Use `docs/current/static` instead of `docs/8.4/static`.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko Why? According to the documentation using `,` is equivalent to `cross join` (and also to `table_one inner join table_two on (true)`).

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko If the question is related to version 8.4 than I think it is appropriate to link to that version.

Comment: First - table list (using `where` to join table) is a bad practice in general. Second - you will have problems if you wish to `JOIN` other tables on top of this two.